# What is the probability of rolling an even number on a die, under the condition that the number is less than 4

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So this problem is greatly confusing me. In the solution, using conditional probability, where A is the event of getting an even number:
 $A=\{2,4,6\}$
 And B is the event of getting a number smaller than 4:
 $B=\{1,2,3\}$
 Then $P(A|B)=P(AB)/P(B)=1/3$
Now, I don't understand why the answer is $1/3$. Isn't this question the same as "what is the probability of rolling an even number that is smaller than 4" for which there is only 1 favorable outcome out of 6 - number 2. So the solution would be $1/6$. What am I missing here? Is the solution miscalculated?

Comment: As you are given that the roll is $<4$ there are only three (equally probable) options, namely $1,2,3$, only one of which is even.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand - I'm not considering the full space of outcomes, just the ones that satisfy the condition of being $<4$, correct?

Comment: Correct.  "The probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ is known to occur" is different than "The probability of $A$ and $B$ occurring"

Comment: Understood. Thank you both. :)